# Echo variable from $_POST["organisation"] only works in sql query and not in sum of result

Tags: php, variables, post, sum, var

From Android I post `name="organisation", value="wwf"`.
In the $sql variable $organisation works but when using same variable in the echo it doesn't.

If `$organisation` is replaced with wwf in the echo works as inteded and returns the amount of users who selected wwf in the database.

Moving around `" .$organistion.` but only get the correct result when hardcode wwf in the sum.

```
$organisation = $_POST["organisation"];

$sql = "select sum(`$organisation`) from `users` where `$organisation`=1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die ("Bad Query: $sql");

while ($count = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    //print_r($count);
    echo"{$count['sum(`$organisation`)']}"; 
}
```

Var `$organisation` in my sql query works as intended but in the echo it doesn't return a value. The var `$organisation` doesn't seem to have the right format to return its value when used in sum from the array print_r produces.

Comment: This SQL statement could lead to a SQL Injection, you may want to look into [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) to prevent that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the column in your SQL an alias so you can get it back out easier:

```
$sql = "select sum(`$organisation`) AS org_count from `users` where `$organisation`=1";
```

Then you can use

```
echo $count['org_count'];
```

to get the value back out.

By the way, you really shouldn't blindly allow `$organisation` from a post value. Check it against existing columns first, or else someone can easily break your query.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it.
Agreed I have some reading up to do on security implications.